# Unable to install Fedora Linux 37 in an old Dell Vostro

Tags: linux, hardware

I installed a new SSD in a Dell Vostro Notebook and want to install Fedora 37 on that machine. I wrote Fedora 37 ISO image on a USB stick, and as I try to boot, I got this error:

```
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM
```

As I turn on the notebook, I get this image:
`No Operational system found.`

Obs: I have already checked the cables.

What should I do?

Comment: Verify that USB is active in BIOS and remove PXE/TFTP Boot

Comment: You need to tell the bios/eufi to boot from the usb stick.

Comment: Just to clarify - PXE means the system's trying to boot from the network, so safe to disable entirely on a personal laptop.

Comment: I opened BIOS setup and accessed tab Boot, got the item Integrated NIC, and disabled it, but nothing changed. I can't use Fedora Live USB to install Fedora 37.